# Serversocket.accept() not accepting connection in server side when implemented in a background service

Tags: android, sockets, service, serversocket, wifi-direct

I am trying to establish a client server socket connection with wifi direct using the demo WiFi direct app. The demo app works fine where the connection is being established when the activity is open but
if I create a background service and try to listen for socket connections, the server running in the background service does not accept connections.
The code is as given below:

```
    Server:

public class MyBackgroundService extends Service implements ChannelListener, ConnectionInfoListener {

 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                // put your socket-code here
                String filename= null;

//                Toast t = Toast.makeText(context,"Opening a server socket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//                t.show();

                DataInputStream inputstream = null;
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
                    Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");

        ....

}

@Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {


        this.info = info;
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG,"FileServeronConneitoninfo Background");
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public class FileTransferService extends IntentService {

private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 0;

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_FILE)) {
            String filename= intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_FILE_PATH);
            String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT);
            DataOutputStream stream = null;
            try {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Opening client socket - ");
                socket.bind(null);
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Opening client socket - ");
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());

                // ...

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "IOException in File transfer");
                Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());

            }
            finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The client side is getting timeout exception and both the lines after the connect and accept are not executing. Is there any possible reason?
I have put timeout 0 to prevent timeout exception but still there are no connections established. This is happening only in the background service but if I do this in activity everything works fine. 
Thanks in advance.

Log Cat Output of server side:

01-28 11:21:12.391  E/wifidirectdemo: COnnection_Change_BackgroundService

01-28 11:21:12.392  E/wifidirectdemo: ConnectionInfo Available Background

01-28 11:21:12.392  E/wifidirectdemo: FileServeronConneitoninfo Background

01-28 11:21:12.394  E/wifidirectdemo: Server: Socket opened

01-28 11:21:22.877 E/wifidirectdemo: P2P peers changed

Comment: Yes the log statement before accept is printed but not the one after it

Comment: Added, all log statements are printed by Log.e.

Comment: On client side the error sometimes is connection refused and sometimes it is connection timeout. Cant understand what the problem is?

Comment: My code. The problem is that this connection thing is not being called in the onstartmethod in my code. It is called once onConnectionInfo returns true after listening to a broadcast as in wifi direct. So it is giving both the exceptions, one or the other.

Comment: Onconnectioninfoavaialble is a method on server side to listen for any wifip2p connection requests and only if devices are connected the socket code is run. It is there in my code above. And onstartmethod is the one you implemented. Pls check the WiFi P2P android guide for further info.

Comment: As I said I don't want this code to be implemented in onstartcommand as you have implemented. Otherwise the difference between my and your code is just the while loop. Nothing different.

Comment: What exception is thrown when you set the connect timeout to zero? NB 1. `socket.bind(null)` is essentially pointless. 2. The socket has to be closed whether it is connected or not.

Comment: Connection timeout after 2-3 minutes.

Comment: NB 3 `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. This is rather strange code altogether. Is this the Android simulator problem where you have to use the address ending in .2?

Comment: No, what is strange about it?